# Lua fix attempt to index a NIL field

Tags: api, lua

I have searched for an answer and this should be simple but I can't find a solution.

I am trying to index data from a json object obtained from a solar inverter.

When the inverter is running the PAC field contains the POWER AC value I want. When the sun sets the field does not drop to 0, it completely disappears from the API response and as such my code throws an ERROR trying to index a field that does not exist.

how can I catch this error and return a 0 when the field is not present?

```
PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value
```

I have tried:

```
PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value or 0
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If `PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value` causes an error for indexing a nil value, `PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value or 0` will cause the same error as you still index the same nil value.

I can only guess that `resp1.Body.Data.PAC` is nil.

Then something like

```
PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC and resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value or 0
```

will work.

This is basically equivalent to

```
if not reps1.Body.Data.PAC then
  PAC = 0
else
  PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value
end
```

Or

```
if reps1.Body.Data.PAC then
  PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value
else
  PAC = 0
end
```

That way you avoid indexing `resp1.Body.Data.PAC` if it is `nil`.

You should find out what exactly is nil.

Comment: I was unable to get the value from PAC unless i specifically reference PAC.value.

Answer (score -1):

I knew it was easy and i feel silly.

I was able to capture the error within a pcall.

```
pcall(function() PAC = resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value end)
if PAC then
  ...
end
```

Comment: instead of forcefully casuing an error by indexing a nil value and than catching it you should simply avoid indexing it in the first place

Comment: How do I avoid indexing it when it is a critical field? I can't seem to find a way to 'test' if the field exists before attempting to index it?

Comment: you test it using an if statement or by using logical operators. see my answer.

Comment: Firstly thank you for taking time to help me.

Now I tried doing exactly that already and it still threw the same error from the if call.

The PAC table has 4 elements, 'unit' constantly = 'wh' and 'value' which has the integer value I want. However, when that field drops to '0' the whole PAC table disappears from the json object response given from API call. Even using an IF statement throws an error when the PAC table is not present in json call.

Comment: `resp1.Body.Data.PAC.Value` is a chain of index operations. find out which of them causes the error. what is nil? `resp1`? `resp1.Body`? `resp1.Body.Data`? `resp1.Body.Data.PAC`?`